# Find product in database with "like" statement in cakephp

Tags: php, database, cakephp, sql-like

I have a function that searches in the database all products with the description like the user search, but it is not working. Where is the problem?

```
 public function searchProduct(){
            $search = $this->request->query('search');
            $products = $this->Product->find("all",array('conditions'=>array('Description LIKE'=>"%$search%")));
            if($this->Auth->user()!= null){
                $userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
                $user = $this->User->findById($userId);
                $filters = $user['Filter'];
                $arrayFiltersOfUser = array();
                $arrayOfProductIds = array();
                for($i = 0; $i < count($filters); $i++){
                    $arrayFiltersOfUser[$i] = $filters[$i]['id'];
                }
                for($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++){
                    $arrayOfProductIds[$i] = $products[$i]['Product']['id'];
                }
                for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayOfProductIds); $i++){
                    $arrayFiltersOfProduct_aux[$i] = $this->FiltersProduct->findAllByProductId($arrayOfProductIds[$i]);
                    $array = $arrayFiltersOfProduct_aux[$i];
                    for($j = 0; $j < count($array); $j++){
                        $array2[$j] = $array[$j]['FiltersProduct']['filter_id'];
                    }
                    $containsAllValues = !array_diff($arrayFiltersOfUser, $array2);
                    if($containsAllValues == true){
                        $this->set("is_valid", "yes");
                        $this->set("_serialize", array("is_valid"));
                    }
                    else{
                        $this->set("is_valid", "no");
                        $this->set("_serialize", array("is_valid"));
                    }
                }
            }
            $this->set("response", $products);
            $this->set("_serialize", array("response"));
        }
```

Comment: All of the code from line 4 onwards appears to be irrelevant to the question.. please *don't* include code that's just a distraction to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're now searching for: %$search% and not the value of $search.

Try to replace

`find("all",array('conditions'=>array('Description LIKE'=>"%$search%")));`

with

`find("all",array('conditions'=>array('Description LIKE'=>"%".$search."%")));`

This should do the trick.

Comment: That's a non-funcional change... strings in double quoted strings are evaluated for variables - this answer doesn't actually change anything.